# Optional argument parsing in R for working directory

Tags: r, parameter-passing

I am parsing argument in a rscript (`merge_em.r`) below. Let's say I run the code below using commandline `Rscript merge_em.r dataframe1, dataframe2`  which gives me this error: `Error in setwd(working.dir) : character argument expected`. I want to keep working directory argument optional. How do I do it?

```
library("argparse")    
merge_em <- function (x, y, working.dir){
      mergedfile <- merge (x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)))
    if (missing(working.dir)) {
      print ("Working directory not specified! Will use present working directory.")
      working.dir <- as.character(file.path(getwd()))
    } else {
      working.dir <- working.dir
    }

    setwd(working.dir)
write.table (mergedfile, "merged.txt",
       col.names = FALSE,
       row.names = FALSE,
       sep = "\t",
       quote = FALSE
)   
}

main <- function() {
  # breaks if you set warn = 2
  options(error = traceback,
          warn = 1)

  parser <- ArgumentParser(prog = "merge_em.r",
                           description = "Merge dataframes")

  parser <- ArgumentParser()
  parser$add_argument("x")
  parser$add_argument("y")
  parser$add_argument(
    "--working_dir",
    dest = "working.dir",
    type = "character",
    metavar = "DIR",
    required = FALSE,
    help = "Working directory where files are present"
  )

  args        <- parser$parse_args()
  working.dir <- args$working.dir

  x  <- args$x
  if (!R.utils::isAbsolutePath(x))
    x <- file.path(working.dir, x)


  y  <- args$y
  if (!R.utils::isAbsolutePath(y))
    y <- file.path(working.dir, y)

  tryCatch(
    merge_em (x, y, working.dir)
      ,
    finally = setwd(working.dir)
  )
}
main()
```

Comment: Is the comma in line 54 necessary? I'm getting an error with it.

Comment: @SeGa Yes. `?tryCatch` : `tryCatch(expr, ..., finally)`

Comment: @SeGa I just noticed this `function (x, y, working.dir)` has to be `merge_em(x, y, working.dir)` in line 53. But still doesn't solve the problem of working.dir.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense and solves my issue.

Comment: I can reproduce your error now, but I am also not able to make it run with a working.dir argument. Which `write` function is that? If its a `base` function I am getting a `too many arguments` error.

Comment: @SeGa that should be 'write.csv'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172261/discussion-between-sega-and-mapk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exchange the missing() conditional to this:

```
  if (working.dir=="") {
    print ("Working directory not specified! Will use present working directory.")
    working.dir <- as.character(file.path(getwd()))
  } else {
    print ("Working directory is specified!")
    working.dir <- working.dir
  }
```

And change the argument for `working_dir` to (*default=""*):

```
  parser$add_argument(
    "--working_dir",
    dest = "working.dir",
    type = "character",
    metavar = "DIR",
    default="",
    required = FALSE,
    help = "Working directory where files are present"
  )
```

And change the `tryCatch` to:

```
  tryCatch(merge_em(x, y, working.dir), finally =  print("Fin"))
```

Why are you using setwd() io the finally part? If the argument is not given, there is nothing to set or?

Like that you can call the script like this, for example:

```
Rscript merge_em.r data_frame1, data_frame2
```

Or with a directory:

```
Rscript merge_em.r data_frame1, data_frame2, --working_dir "path_to_folder"
```

Full code:

```
library(argparse)    

merge_em <- function (x, y, working.dir){

  mergedfile <- merge (x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)))

  if (working.dir=="") {
    print ("Working directory not specified! Will use present working directory.")
    working.dir <- as.character(file.path(getwd()))
  } else {
    print ("Working directory is specified!")
    working.dir <- working.dir
  }
  setwd(working.dir)

  write.csv(x = mergedfile, file = "merged.txt",
            row.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE
  ) 
}

main <- function() {
  # breaks if you set warn = 2
  options(error = traceback,
          warn = 1)

  parser <- ArgumentParser(prog = "merge_em.r",
                           description = "Merge dataframes")
  parser <- ArgumentParser()
  parser$add_argument("x")
  parser$add_argument("y")
  parser$add_argument(
    "--working_dir",
    dest = "working.dir",
    type = "character",
    metavar = "DIR",
    default="",
    required = FALSE,
    help = "Working directory where files are present"
  )

  args        <- parser$parse_args()
  working.dir <- args$working.dir

  x  <- args$x
  if (!R.utils::isAbsolutePath(x))
    x <- file.path(working.dir, x)

  y  <- args$y
  if (!R.utils::isAbsolutePath(y))
    y <- file.path(working.dir, y)

  tryCatch(merge_em(x, y, working.dir), finally =  print("Fin"))
}

main()
```

Comment: I have a very complex code and I was using `setwd()` just to simulate whether the parsed argument for `working.dir` can be executed this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it as a default and override it when necessary.

```
merge_em <- function (x, y, working.dir = getwd()){
  mergedfile <- merge (x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)))
  setwd(working.dir)
  write (mergedfile, "merged.txt",
       col.names = FALSE,
       row.names = FALSE,
       sep = "\t",
       quote = FALSE
  )   
}
```

And override it with some other value:

```
merger_em(x, y, 'another/path/dir')
```

I haven't tested this, but default parameters are a standard in many languages.

Also, you can setwd with getwd like: `setwd(getwd())`

Comment: What is the output of getwd()

Comment: `getwd()` gives me the working directory when I run the code on Rstudio interactively, but not with commandline (still gives error).

Comment: Sorry, I can't recreate. `getwd()` and `setwd(getwd())` work in my command line with no error. It's a different directory than the one set in an R-Studio script, but it works nonetheless.